# Orientation error for images uploaded to GAE (GCS + get_serving_url)

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, google-app-engine-python

We are developing an image sharing service using GAE. Many users have reported since last week that "portrait images are oriented in landscape".
We found out that from a specific timing, the specification of images uploaded and distributed through GAE has changed.

So the specs seem to have changed around 3/18 03:25(UTC) .
The "orientation" of Exif is not properly applied.

We are using GAE/Python. We save images uploaded by the users to GoogleCloudStorage, then use the URL we get with get_serving_url to distribute them.

Is this problem temporal?
Also, is it possible to return to the specs before 3/18 03:22(UTC)?

Answer (score -1):

I think it happens because when get_serving_url service resize the image, it always resize the image from the longest side of the Image, keeping the aspect ration same. If you have a image of 1600x2400, then the resize image is 106x160 to keep the aspect ratio is same.

In your case one of the image is 306x408 (which is correct)as Image is resized from the height, and the other image is  360x270 (in which orientation change) the image is resized from width. I think in the later-one the orientation is changed just to keep the aspect ratio same.

Comment: No. It, as is written in the description, is a matter of neither the browser nor appengine reading the EXIF-tag of the jpg. For some reason, many cellphones save the images rotated, with information in EXIF for the viewer to rotate back in presentation.